# Is there a way to automatically call all the getter methods on an object graph?

Tags: java

I have a collection of java bean objects and each object can have another collection of java bean objects (ie object graph).  Is there an easy way to traverse the graph and call all the getter methods?  Is there a library already doing something similar like that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at BeanInfo:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html

and especially the getPropertyDescriptors() method.

Answer (score 1):

[java.beans.Introspector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)  should allow you to traverse all the properties and methods of the beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reflection** to do so manually.

Also take look at common-beanutils, there might be something to help.

Comment: Using java.beans instead of java.reflect will handle all the beans conventions for you, and it's also a little safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a library called FEST for some automated testing and it has a reflection library that works well for me.

http://fest.easytesting.org/reflect/wiki/pmwiki.php